# How to get the gap between years using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a data frame like this

```
Series_id  F start end data

3               A     2012 2018  [[2012,0],[2014,0],[2015,1],[2017,3],[2019,0],[2020.1]]
```

I need Output like this

{series_id:3,start:2013,end:2013,count:1},{series_id:3,start:2016,end:2016,count:1}{series_id:3,start:2018,end:2018,count:1},

I have to iterate over the data frame of each row and find the gap between year in the data column The data column is a list of a list which has the year and some data in each list

I have to check with consecutive and missing years and count.
count example: take series id:3 start=2014 end=2018 on iterating the 2013,2016 and 2018 are missed but in between, 2017 is there so for that I have to get like this
{series_id:3,start:2013,end:2013,count:1},
{series_id:3,start:2016,end:2016,count:1},{series_id:3,start:2018,end:2018,count:1}

How can I achieve this even I not able to iterate it?
Please Need a help

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting the `count`.  Also why do you have random duplicate entries?

Comment: I have improved the Question

Comment: Thanks for improving. Still hard to understand. Your result contains `{series_id:2,start:2013,end:2013,count:1}` but there is no 2013 in Series_id:2. Please explain.

Comment: What I need is the missing years in the result.2013 is missing between 2012 and 2014 so for that.

Comment: Please post a simple understandable dataframe and a expected output for that

Comment: given simple data frame. can you check to give a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to convert a query operation performed on a pandas dataframe into a list. There is a method called as to_json() on pandas.
Find the link below to see examples and implementation.

[enter link description here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

Use orient = records
Then you can use [json.loads()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to convert to a list.

Now you can iterate over it.